# Test Javascript method calling in WebView [Robolectric]

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, junit, robolectric

I'm trying to test whether Javascript method (registered as an interface in WebView) is called or not. Following sample works when executed within standard app flow, but it doesn't work when I try to run it like a Robolectric test.
Anybody knows why?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
class ExampleUnitTest {

    private lateinit var activityController: ActivityController<Activity>
    private lateinit var activity: Activity
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    val signal = CountDownLatch(1)
    var success = false

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(Activity::class.java)
        activity = activityController.get()
        webView = WebView(activity)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "example")
    }

    @Test
    fun getUuid() {
        System.out.println("Ping")
        webView.evaluateJavascript("example.pong();", null);
        signal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        Assert.assertTrue(success)
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun pong() {
        System.out.println("Pong")
        success = true
        signal.countDown()
    }
}
```

Comment: did you resolved this issue ?